# lJSON-LD Syntax error: value, object or array expected

Tags: json

I am just trying to get our events onto google using markup and I am fairly new to all of this so I hope someone can help I have just checked the following and got the error above

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": “Staunton Harold Sportive”,
  "startDate": "2019-05-26T08:00",
  "endDate": "2019-05-26T17:00",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": “Staunton Harold Hall”,
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": “Melbourne Road”,
      "addressLocality": “Ashby De la Zouch“,
      "postalCode": "LE65 1RT",
      "addressRegion": “Derbyshire”,
      "addressCountry": "UK”

    }
  },
  "image": [

    "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/36c4d1_84383c3423f0429b8fe7988a0382dbb0~mv2_d_3905_2194_s_2.png/v1/fill/w_1084,h_608,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/Staunton%20Harold%20sportive.png",

   ],
  "description": " 
Fun - 14K
Short - 40K
Medium - 100K
Long - 160K  The Staunton Harold Sportive starts from the privately owned, estate in the stunning surroundings of Staunton Harold Hall  estate, providing the perfect backdrop for a fun and enjoyable bike ride.",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "https://www.triathlon-events.com/staunton-harold-sportive",
    "price": “20",
    "priceCurrency": “GBP”,
    "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
    "validFrom": "2018-05-26T16:00"
  },
  “Organizer”: {
    "@type": “Organizer”,
    "name": “Choose Sports Ltd”
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you have curly quotation marks in places instead of straight ones e.g. “Staunton Harold Sportive” needs to have the straight quotations marks as used in "https://schema.org".  I'd start by swapping those out and retest.  Hope that helps.